# Pass data form controller to ajax and modal laravel 8

Tags: php, ajax, bootstrap-modal, laravel-8, bootstrap-5

I tried to pass data from controller to ajax but data didnt come to my modal

This My Controller :

```
 public function grd_checkout($paket)
    {
        $data= Voucher::where([
            ['paket',$paket],
            ['lokasi','GRD.NET']
        ])->count();

        return response()->json([
            'stok' => $data,
        ]); 
    }
```

This My Route :

```
Route::get('menu/grd_checkout/{paket}', [MenuController::class, 'grd_checkout']);
```

Button :

```
<td align="center" >
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-id="{{ $voucher->paket }}" 
data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#myModal">Beli
</button>
</td>
```

This My Form Modal :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
        <div class="modal-content modal-sm">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="myModalLongTitle">Isi Data Diri dan Jumlah Pemesanan</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close"  data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                Stok Voucher Tersedia : <p id="stok"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This My Ajax :

```
<script>
    $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
  let paket = $(this).data('id');
  $.ajax({
            url: '/menu/grd_checkout/' + paket,
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(data) {
                $('#stok').text(data.stok);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Please kinda help to solve my error, the "stok" didnt shown up in modal, Thanks for helping!

Comment: Can You Use $('#stok').html(data.stok); insted of  $('#stok').text(data.stok);

Comment: thanks for answering, but still doesnt working

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check the response of the API and if it's okay then kindly try this:

```
<script>
    $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
       var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
       var paket = $(this).data('id');

       $.ajax({
            url: '/menu/grd_checkout/' + paket,
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(data) {
                $(document).find('#stok').html(data.stok);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks man but i already solved it by change the "let paket = $(this).data('id');" to "var paket = button.data('id');"

Comment: Cool! keep coding and have a good day ;)